# How can I remove `nx` default output?

Tags: node.js, nx-monorepo

I have a customer target in nx project file:

```
"targets":{
  "hello": {
      "executor": "nx:run-commands",
      "options": {
        "command": "echo Hello"
      }
    }
```

when I run the command `nx hello my-project`, it outputs:

```
> nx run my-project

hello



 >  NX   Successfully ran target sonar for project my-project (105ms)
```

How can I remove the extra logs from `nx` and only keep `hello` in the output?

Comment: There isn't an option to configure. See https://github.com/nrwl/nx/blob/master/packages/nx/src/tasks-runner/life-cycles/static-run-one-terminal-output-life-cycle.ts#L62